# If url variable is empty redirect to home page

Tags: php, isset

I am not able to get this to work correctly!!

I have a view.php page that uses a variable of 'ID' to retrieve db info.

So my url is like this:

```
/view.php?id=23
```

I am trying to get it to "redirect" the user to the home page if they erase the "23" part of the url.. ?

so when you visit

```
/view.php?id=
```

It should :

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) == "") 
{ 
header('Location: /');
exit; }
```

Works if I visit

```
/view.php
```

Comment: isset returns a boolean true or false. isset($_GET['id']) == "" will always be false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if(empty($_GET['id'])) 
{ 
  header('Location: /');
  exit; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
if(strlen($_GET['id'])>0) { 
 header('Location: /');
 exit; 
}
```